# Oracle query not displaying date properly

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

In Oracle, there is a column(dateColumn) in a table with column type = DATE and the value for a particular record is showing as '10/03/2010' when I do a `select * from table.`
Now, when I do:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE dateColumn < '01-JAN-11'
```

Nothing shows up. When I do:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE dateColumn > '01-JAN-11'
```

The record shows up.
Why is this behaving this way? "10/03/2010" is 10th MArch 2010 so clearly that is < 01 Jan 2011.

Comment: I find it useful to set the specific date format I want by the following command set nls_date_format= 'mm/dd/yyyy'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no definitive date format -- it can be different by region or even business.  That's the reality without even considering SQL...

In Oracle, the means of evaluating a string as a date requires you to use the [TO_DATE function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE dateColumn > TO_DATE('01-JAN-11', 'DD-MON-YY')
```

You need to supply the format mask to instruct Oracle how to interpret the date you're supplying it.

The function is often different on other databases, but the experience is otherwise the same.  Most databases accept 'YYYY-MM-DD' for implicit conversion of a string into a date.  Explicit conversion is when you use a function, like `TO_DATE` to explicitly change the data type.

Comment: Thank you.if the sql were inside a function and we need to call the function, passing the date as input, it is not working for me. So I do: SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE dateColumn > TO_DATE(inputDate, 'DD-MON-YY'); And I call it passing input date. It gives me syntax error

Comment: @Kaushik: What is the data type of the parameter `inputDate`?  I'll wager it's `DATE`, which is not the question you asked.  I will never understand why people think hiding details is a good idea...

Comment: Yes right. The data type is DATE. What am I doing worng here? Thank you

Comment: @Kaushik: If the parameter is `DATE`, then you don't need to use `TO_DATE` in the query contained in the function/sproc.  But the date format is still an issue, just pushed up to when you call the function.

Comment: Can you please explain. If I non't need to use TO_DATE, what is the solution for the problem?

Comment: @Kaushik: I don't know how to explain it more than I already did in my previous comment.  The parameter data type means you still have the issue, but only when making the function call if supplying a string that is to be interpreted by Oracle as a date.

Comment: @Kaushik -- if you are calling `my_func('01-JAN-11')`, and the parameter of the function is a DATE, then the string is being implicitly converted to a date using the default format.  To control the format, you could use TO_DATE in the call to the function, e.g. `my_func( TO_DATE('01-JAN-11','DD-MON-YY') )`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use to_date:

```
select * from table where dateColumn < to_date('01-JAN-11', 'dd-MON-YY')
```

Comment: Changed "mm" to "MON", because "mm" is for numeric month.